# An exception occurs while creating storage account in Azure through API in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

`enter code here` I have created a class to get the token that is needed to create the credentials then while creating storage account in azure environment using c# an exception "The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription" occurs. Please let me know how to to resolve this issue?

```
 public async static Task<string> CreateStorageAccount(SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials)
        {
            using (var storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(credentials))
            {
                await storageClient.StorageAccounts.CreateAsync(

                  new StorageAccountCreateParameters
                  {
                      AccountType = "Standard_GRS",
                      // AccountType = AccountType.StandardLRS, Location = "West US"
                      //GeoReplicationEnabled = false,
                      Label = "Sample Storage Account",
                      Location = LocationNames.EastAsia,
                      Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageName"]
                  });
            }
            return "Successfully created account.";
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: How are you creating `SubscriptionCloudCredentials`?

Comment: I have added the application in active directory and generated the client id using that input  in my c# application ,I have created the SubscriptionCloudCredentials.

Comment: Just wanted to ensure that you have used `TokenCloudCredentials` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.tokencloudcredentials_members%28v=azure.11%29.aspx).

Comment: yes, I Have used TokenCloudCredentials.

Comment: Did you try alternatives, such as using a connection string rather than certificate?